# IndexError: list index out of range:

Tags: python

how i can to fix this code
i want to check if the key is like inside the list keys it
i also i want
if  the key is true can user  the use the tool if the key is false the user cant use the tool

```py
keys
    {
        "link": "www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com",  
        "key": '34243242354354'
    },
    {
        "link": "www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com",
        "key": '432432534534534'
    },
    {
        "link": "www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com",
        "key": '42345534534'
    }
]
number = 0 
key = input("put the code to use this tool :")
for x in keys:
    number = number + 1 
    if keys[number]["key"] == key:
       print("true")
    else:
       print("false")
```

Comment: thanks for you guys for help me 
 the Issue is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see here there are 3 problems:

1. The counter shouldn't be before the execution of the IF statement.
2. You should put the **break** after the 'true' statement.
3. You need a better condition instead of **else**

You can do this:

```
number = 0

key = input("put the code to use this tool :")

for x in keys:
    
    if keys[number]["key"] == key:
        print("true")
        break
        
    elif number == (len(keys) - 1):
        print("false")
        
    number = number + 1
```

Or also better to use the **enumerate**:

```
number = 0

key = input("put the code to use this tool :")

for number, x in enumerate(keys):
    
    if keys[number]["key"] == key:
        print("true")
        break
        
    elif number == (len(keys) - 1):
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should try the enumerate() for index loops.

```
def key_func():
    key = input("put the code to use this tool :")
    for i ,m in enumerate(keys):
        if m['key'] == key:
            return True
    return False
```